# The response from the remote server was: Message rejected when sending mail via xampp localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp

i'm trying to send mail via PHP code

I'm using Xampp v3.2.2,

I have configured XAMPP to send mail from localhost just like this:

in php.ini :

extension=php_openssl.dll

SMTP=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

sendmail_from = my_id@gmail.com

sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

in sendmail function, in sendmail.ini:

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=587

error_logfile=error.log

debug_logfile=debug.log

auth_username=my_id@gmail.com

auth_password=my_id_password

force_sender=my_id@gmail.com

i'm very sure that this configuration is right, my code is:

```html
<?php
$to = "another_id@hotmail.com";
$subject = "wa a5iran zobtet";
$txt = "Hello world! My first mail with PHP";
$headers = "From: Someone" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

the message is sent but i got this :

Message blocked

Your message has been blocked by another_id@hotmail.com. See technical details below for more information.

The response from the remote server was:
Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

Comment: Wheres your php code to send the email?

Comment: bro i edited my question, i got another problem now after fixing the first problem